# Make method work on object

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I am trying to make a method that I have made (lets call it custom method) to act.

Basically I am parsing JSON info and getting the latitude (then eventually I'll get logitude via the same way, not same method though, a different one made the same, if that makes sense). When I use the below it works and I get the string.

```
NSString *mapStringLatitude = [[[[self.mapPlacesDictionary objectForKey:@"result"]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]valueForKey:@"lat"];
```

This returns (via `NSLog`):

```
mapStringLatitude: 37.790943
```

Which is correct. I want to make the code easier to read though. So I want a method such as getLatitude to do the drilling down for me. What I have below:

```
-(NSString *)getLatitude
{
    NSString *getLatitude = [[[[self.mapPlacesDictionary objectForKey:@"result"]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]valueForKey:@"lat"];
    return getLatitude;
}
```

I want this method to be used instead of the above line. Basically I am looking here: http://bit.ly/1bh9o9R

It states, `[someobject method]`, which I am unable to do i.e. `[self.mapDictionary getLatitude]` does not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why?

Attached as requested. The aftermath.[image]

Comment: 1. what does "does not work" mean *precisely?* Compiler error? Runtime error? 2. Are you aware that you have to call the method on the object on which you implemented it? `[dict getLatitude]` won't work if the `getLatitude` method is not a part of `NSDictionary` but another class. 3. **Do not prefix your method with `get`, this is not Java.** Getters don't have that prefix, prefer `latitude` instead.

Comment: Xcode autocompletes, I am unable to autocomplete. Ok, I will remove the get, habit. I then tried ViewController *c = [ViewController alloc]init] then c.mapPlacesDictionary and still no luck. When I try [self getLatitude] it compiles but then crashes at run time. Do you know how I can use such a method?

Comment: If it crashes at runtime, please post the error message shown. I suspect you are still calling it on an object of different class than you implemented it in.

Comment: I think what you did wrong is: [self.mapDictionary getLatitude] it must be [self getLatitude]

Comment: Greetings hasan, please look at the image again, I believe that is in there as [self getLatitude]. I tried again and it appears correct. Perhaps you are looking at the above dictionary. The first self. is fine I believe.

Comment: The picture shows you stopped at a debugger breakpoint.  That doesn't tell anything about a crash or error.

Comment: Thank you very much Philip, I cleared the breakpoints and that solved it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`.  That is reserved for a very particular usage pattern and this isn't it.  It should just be `latitude`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your code a lot shorter using

```
NSString *latitude = [self.mapPlacesDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"result.geometry.location.lat"];
```

Or even go crazy like:

```
#define kLatKeyPath @"result.geometry.location.lat"
/* ... later */
NSString *lat = [self.mapPlacesDictionary valueForKeyPath:kLatKeyPath];
```